# JQuery: What does $(this).data('pinned') actually do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that is basically 3 buttons and 3 hidden carousels.  When you hover over a button it previews it's carousel and when you click it it shows the carousel.

To disable the hover preview effect from hiding the carousel on click I used the code: `$(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));` and it works but I'm not sure why.  Can anyone explain why it keeps showing the carousel?

```
 $('#button01')
    .hover(function() {
        if (!($(this).data('pinned')) && !($(this).hasClass('disabled'))) {
            $('#carousel01').toggle('slide');
        }
    })

    .click ( function () {
        // cancel hover effect and pin carousel
        $(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));

        // disable other options
        if (!($(this).hasClass('disabled'))) {
            $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');
            $('#button02').toggleClass('disabled');
            $('#button03').toggleClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

I would expect the `.data('pinned')` function to have applied only to the button.  Does it apply to the entire visible page? I tried to look it up but I see nothing about using 'pinned' with the .data() function.

I orginally got the code from here: [Unpinning a div on document click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804321/unpinning-a-div-on-document-click/13804436#13804436)

Relevent HTML:

```
    <div class="jumbotron">


        <div class="container">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg displayed" id="button01" href="#" height="175" width="175">
                    <p class="centered"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg displayed" id="button02" href="#" height="175" width="175">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class=" btn btn-default btn-lg displayed" id="button03" href="#" height="175" width="175">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel01" class="carousel slide wizard">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <h2>Slide 01<br />
                <small>subheading</small></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carousel01" role="button" data-slide="next">Continue</a>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h2>Slide 02<br />
                    <small>subheading</small></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carousel01" role="button" data-slide="next">Next</a>
            </div>

         <div id="carousel02" class="carousel slide wizard">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <h2>Slide 01<br />
                <small>subheading</small></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carousel02" role="button" data-slide="next">Continue</a>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h2>Slide 02<br />
                    <small>subheading</small></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#carousel02" role="button" data-slide="next">Next</a>
            </div>   

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery data function just allows you to store arbitrary data associated with the DOM (HTML) node. If we break down the code that you have, it looks like this:

```
 $('#button01') //Select the element with an ID of button01
    .hover(function() { //Whenever your cursor moves in or out of the node, run this function
        if (!($(this).data('pinned')) && !($(this).hasClass('disabled'))) { //If you haven't set it to be pinned
            $('#carousel01').toggle('slide'); //Show or hide the carousel
        }
    })
```

So whenever you move the cursor on or off the button, it will check whether it has been pinned and show it if it's hidden or hide it if it's shown (that's what `.toggle` does).

```
    .click ( function () { //Any time you click (or tap) the button
        // cancel hover effect and pin carousel
        $(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));
```

While inside a jQuery event (such as `.click`), `$(this)` refers to the element that the event was triggered on, which is the button in this case. Calling `$(this).data('pinned')`, as your code does at the end of the line, returns the current value of the data associated with this element that has an id of "pinned". The `!` negates it, so if it was true, we get false, and if it was false, we get true. The value that we get from that is then set as the new data attribute, so that if it was pinned, we set it to not be pinned.

Here is a more verbose way of writing it:

```
var currentPinnedStatus = $(this).data('pinned'); //Get the current pinned status
if (currentPinnedStatus == true) {
    var newPinnedStatus = false;
} else {
    var newPinnedStatus = true;
}
$(this).data('pinned', newPinnedStatus); //set the new pinned status
```

Then when you remove your cursor from the button, it checks whether the pinned data is set to false, and only hides the carousel if so. When you move your cursor back onto the button it checks whether pinned is set to false again, and only shows it if so.

For more information on the jQuery data function, you can take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I see, 'pinned' could be anything.. like 'pressed' or 'clicked' and it would work the same.  I thought there was something inherently special about 'pinned' but I see now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze the below code:

```
$('#button01')                                        // The button's jQuery Object.
  .click ( function () {                              // Click event handler binding.
    $(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));  // this refers to the <input />
  });
```

The `$(this).data()` function gets the `data-` attribute from the `<input />`.

The `$(this).data('pinned')` gets the value of `data-pinned` value.

Now, it could be anything. It will be returning in `string` format. So, when the value is like: `true`:

```
$(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));
```

This becomes `false`. It is just for a type conversion. This is common in JavaScript and other programming language, and you can say this as a shortcut for converting any type of variable into `boolean`.

So, when you have something like a string:

```
var a = "true";  // string: true
b = !a;          // bool: false;
c = !!true;      // bool: true
```

Hope it is clear. The above code toggles between true and false for the `data-pinned` attribute when you click.

> **Note:** As people have said in the comments: Note that `.data()` does not only checks for the HTML `data-` attribute, but also looks within the jQuery `data` object for the selected element(s).

Comment: note that using `data()` is not totally dependent on there being a `data-` attribute

Comment: @charlietfl I just explained what does that do right? Should I reword?

Comment: just pointing out that if it is used as a setter on element that doesn't have an attribute it does the same thing when used as getter

Comment: Note that `.data()` does not *only* checks for the HTML `data-` attribute, but also looks within the jQuery `data` object for the selected element(s).